# How to connect to different database using ASP.NET with MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am new in ASP.NET but developed systems in Qt platform.I want to get data from a different database and use it in my aplication and save it to my database. I am using ASP.NET and C# through MVC3 approach.

I tried it thru:

Having connection strings to different databases in web.config file as follows.

```
<add name="DBSContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DBS_Example_DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

<add name="VIPSContext"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\VIPS.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Connecting to those two databases in controller as follows

```
private DBSContext db = new DBSContext();
private VIPSContext vipsdb = new VIPSContext();
```

Passing data from controller to view[which is successful] and saving it to DB[unsuccessful] through get and post methods

```
// GET: /Create
public ActionResult Create()
{ 
    //dropdown
    ViewBag.CollectorID =new SelectList(db.Collectors, "CollectorID", "FirstName");
    //dropdown
    ViewBag.TaxpayerID =new SelectList(vipsdb.Taxpayers, "TaxpayerID", "FirstName");

    return View();
} 

// POST: /Create
public ActionResult Create(Debt_Case debt_case)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         db.Debt_Cases.Add(debt_case);
         db.SaveChanges(); //this is where the error is
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(debt_case);
}
```

The error arise when I am saving the changes to the databases.

My model is as follows:

```
public class Debt_Case
{
   public string Debt_CaseID { get; set; }

      public string TaxpayerID { get; set; }
      public string CollectorID { get; set; }
      public string TotalPayment { get; set; }

      public virtual Collector Collectors { get; set; }
      public virtual Taxpayer Taxpayers { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**NB:** the navigation properties namely Collectors and Taxpayers are null.

I am getting this error:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception
>   for details.

Can any one help on how to solve this error.

Comment: What does the inner exception say?

Comment: It says: {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Debt_Case_dbo.Taxpayers_TaxpayerID\". The conflict occurred in database \"DBS_EXAMPLE_DB_3755dd87e8f74dbc86a40b300cff6e72\", table \"dbo.Taxpayers\", column 'TaxpayerID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: Your error says that your DebtCase is either missing your TaxpayerID, or that your TaxpayerID is invalid (there isn't a corresponding row in your TaxPayer table)

Comment: Thnks Christofer for making me check the inner exception. I declared the PK from different db table to be a FK in my application DB hence it creates an entity for me. During INSERT, there was no corresponding FK in a presently created table which is in my application database. Removing FK made it not to automatically build an entity for me hence worked fine. Thank guyz!!

Comment: Thnx Mark, the problm was with TaxpayerID as mentioned above. It is realy working now.